# Makefile: Adding 2nd directory for .h and .cpp files

Tags: makefile

I am adapting my Makefile to look into 4 directories, rather than 2 (it had one for source files and one for header files, but I've added a new folder for common source and include). I have something like follows:

```
CC = g++
FLAGS = -g -c

BUILDDIR = build
INCLUDEDIR = -Icode/inc -I../common/code/inc -I/usr/include/libxml2

SOURCEDIR = code/src ../common/code/src
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.cpp)
OBJECTS = $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp,$(BUILDDIR)/%.o,$(SOURCES))

EXECUTABLE = Exec

all: $(BUILDDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE)

$(BUILDDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ -lpthread -lxml2

$(OBJECTS): $(BUILDDIR)/%.o : $(SOURCEDIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $< $(INCLUDEDIR) -o $@ -Wno-write-strings
```

I tried to add one entry to INCLUDEDIR as follows:

```
-I../common/code/inc
```

And added ../common/code/src to SOURCEDIR:

```
SOURCEDIR = code/src ../common/code/src
```

This is not currently working and I am wondering how to fix it please. I am getting the error:

```
Makefile:27: target `code/src' doesn't match the target pattern
```

but I cannot find how to fix it so far. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: After following MadScientist response below, I am getting the following output:

```
g++    -c -o code/src/Client.o code/src/Client.cpp
code/src/Client.cpp:1:20: fatal error: Client.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [code/src/Client.o] Error 1
```

Updated Makefile:

```
SOURCEDIR = code/src ../common/code/src
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(addsuffix /*.cpp,$(SOURCEDIR)))
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)

$(BUILDDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ -lpthread -lxml2

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o : ../common/code/src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $< $(INCLUDEDIR) -o $@ -Wno-write-strings

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o : code/src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $< $(INCLUDEDIR) -o $@ -Wno-write-strings
```

PS:

I was able to fix it using the following:

```
SOURCEDIR = code/src ../common/code/src
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(addsuffix /*.cpp,$(SOURCEDIR)))
TEMP_OBJ = $(SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)
NOT_DIR = $(notdir $(TEMP_OBJ))
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/, $(NOT_DIR))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, because now your static pattern rule expands to:

```
$(OBJECTS): build/%.o : code/src ../common/code/src/%.cpp
```

which is illegal syntax.  If you avoid using static pattern rules, and instead use pattern rules, then it will just work.  Replace your single static pattern rule with two pattern rules:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o : code/src/%.cpp
        $(CC) $(FLAGS) $< $(INCLUDEDIR) -o $@ -Wno-write-strings

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o : ../common/code/src/%.cpp
        $(CC) $(FLAGS) $< $(INCLUDEDIR) -o $@ -Wno-write-strings
```

EDIT: you also need to change other uses of SOURCEDIR:

```
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(addsuffix /*.cpp,$(SOURCEDIR))
OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.cpp,$(BUILDDIR)/%.o,$(notdir $(SOURCES)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! It seems that it is not trying to run those two rules, it's printing: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'. I tried adding $(OBJECTS) Is $(OBJECTS) needed please? IT doesn't seem to help.

Comment: I'd think I would need $(BUILDDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(BUILDDIR)/%.o, but I am getting "No rule to make target `build/%.o". Thank you.

Comment: Oh, your patsubst is also wrong.  Basically anywhere you used SOURCEDIR and were expecting it to be a single directory, needs to be changed to allow more than one directory.  See edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Sorry if my question is stupid, but I am getting a lot of "target `code/src/main.o' doesn't match the target pattern", I must have done something wrong. It's printing all the files with this error, I am not sure why it doesn't match the pattern though.

Comment: First, see my latest update.  Second, if you're getting that error then you're still using static pattern rules.  You should not have any rule that starts `$(OBJECTS) : ...`.  Replace that with the rules _exactly_ as I've written them above.  If that doesn't work please update your question and add the new content you have.

Comment: My apologies MadScientist. Removing $(OBJECTS): (having exactly your changes) gives me the following error: g++    -c -o code/src/Client.o code/src/Client.cpp
code/src/Client.cpp:1:20: fatal error: Client.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated. It appears it is not using the INCLUDEDIR variable I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was able to fix it with a tiny update! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure why my version didn't work; it looks equivalent to yours.  But anyway, glad you got it working.